# How does the number of JOIN statements effect the duration/fetchtime of a query? I have a simple, counter-intuitive example

Tags: mysql, sql

Im writing some simple queries for my first RDB using MySQL Workbench. Im saving this particular query as a stored procedure. In doing so I uncovered an unexpected result concerning the # of JOIN statements and the duration/fetchtime of queries.

Initially, I (accidentally) joined 2 tables rather than 3 (a `customers` table, a `devices` table, and a mapping table `client_devices`). When I tested it I recorded the duration and fetch time. When I realized my mistake, re-wrote the query to include another JOIN statement, and recorded the duration I was surprised to find that it took half as long despite being more nuanced... Im very curious why this is.

```
-- 1) This is the first "flawed" query 

SELECT
  first_name,
  last_name,
  email,
  phone
FROM customers c
JOIN client_devices cd
  USING (customer_id)
WHERE cd.device_id = target_device_id;
```

```
-- 2) This is the second, "correct" query   

SELECT
  d.device_name,
  first_name,
  last_name,
  email,
  phone
FROM customers c
JOIN client_devices cd
  USING (customer_id)
JOIN devices d
  USING (device_id)
WHERE cd.device_id = target_device_id;
```

If I had been asked before running these queries, I would have assumed that the longer one with 2 JOINs would have definitely taken longer than shorter query with only 1. But, in fact, it ended up being the opposite.

1) 1st query duration/fetchtime

0.0011 sec / 0.000011 sec

2) 2nd query duration/fetchtime

0.00068 sec / 0.000010 sec

Why is this the case???

I really want to understand this as I am intending to train into a DBA role (eventually lol)

PS-1: I am using a micro dataset of only 5 records per table

PS-2: `target_device_id` is an INT parameter for the stored procedure that this query belongs to.

Thank you.

Comment: Execution time for queries on tables with 5 records are really just random noise. To analyze your queries and to see what MySQL decided to do, you have to look at the [explain plan of your query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execution-plan-information.html). If you need help understanding those (and to get an estimate if those make sense), add both to your question. Anyway, a trivial example how your 2nd query can be faster: `devices` could be empty. Or just random noise.

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see the query execution plan. Differences in elapsed times are usually explained by differences in query execution plans, but with only five rows in each table, the time spent for parsing the statement and evaluating possible plans is going to dwarf the actual execute time. It's counterproductive to evaluate performance with trivial sets. Use production sized sets. And then execute each statement multiple times (with query cache disabled) and discard the time for the first execution, and average the time for the remaining executions.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you both. Is there a particular set size which would qualify as production level? 1000+? I’ll use a dummy data generator

Comment: I would avoid the use of using - if for no other reason that you have to dig into the schema definitions to discover how it is joining

Answer (score 0):

> I am using a micro dataset of only 5 records per table

If you want to be a DBA, one of the first things you will need to learn is how the size of the data affects query plans and query execution.  You cannot generalize from a small data set to a large data set.

More importantly, it is often the case that more joins result in faster queries.  The primary reason is due to filtering.  The duration of a query depends both on the number of processing steps and on the amount of data being processed.

For instance, you can always add something like this to a query:

```
from a join
     b
     on . . .  join
     c
     on . . . join
     d
     on 1 = 0
```

The final `join` condition filters out all the rows, so the result set is empty.  That is likely to be much faster than the query without that condition.

Comment: As a total novice I thought that more joins would = more processing because it would be like adding more steps to a recipe. So, in reality, the query is read and the conditions are used to slice away at the table(s) and then the remaining records are read in full? The time/power used to filter through the tables is much much less then the time/power used to read and return the remaining records? (the records that comprise the result set)

Comment: Sorry if my questions are dumb, this is a necessary embarrassment on my part.